# npm install - packages with `git+https://` protocol

Tags: git, npm, ssh, https, bitbucket

I have these two deps in package.json:

```
"cdt-core": "git+https://gitscm.nabisco.com/scm/it-gats-cdtechnologyarchitecture-cdtsdaas/cdt-core.git",
"cdt-models": "git+https://gitscm.nabisco.com/scm/it-gats-cdtechnologyarchitecture-cdtsdaas/cdt-models.git"
```

I can install them fine on my local machine.
If I try to install them from inside a Docker container on my machine, I get:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t https://gitscm.cisco.com/scm/it-gats-cdtechnologyarchitecture-cdtsdaas/cdt-core.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitscm.cisco.com/scm/it-gats-cdtechnologyarchitecture-cdtsdaas/cdt-core.git/'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

does anyone know what the culprit might be? Is it an SSH keys thing? Copying my SSH keys to the container might work, but in some cases we have to build the image on remote machines (on Jenkins, or whatever), so I might need a solution that doesn't just work locally.

**If I provide my credentials explicitly in the container, *it works*:**

```
"cdt-core": "git+https://USER:PASSWORD@gitscm.nabisco.com/scm/it-gats-cdtechnologyarchitecture-cdtsdaas/cdt-core.git"
```

but I don't want to include plaintext password in there. So how do I do this without SSH keys?

Comment: Your SSH keys don't make any difference when the target URL is HTTPS.

Comment: yeah that's what I was thinkin, but then why does `git+https://` fail from inside a Docker container

Comment: Are you providing your credentials anyplace in the container?

Comment: @JimRedmond yeah definitely not provided credentials, maybe I can include the credentials as part of the string?

Comment: maybe use this? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

Comment: I don't explicitly provide the credentials locally, so that's why I don't understand why I need them in the container.

Comment: Seems like for Docker and Jenkins, SSH keys is much better than using username/password in some file or connection string.